# RoR: How to authenticate user before POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, redirect, authentication

I have a form that users can fill out, and hitting the "Create" button will issue a POST request to create a new entry in the database with the form data.

Now, only logged in users should be allowed to create the database entry, but I want all users to be able to fill out the form. Only when clicking "Create" do I want my application to redirect users who are not logged in to the login page. Once logged in, I want to continue processing the POST request and create the database entry, without the user having to enter all the form data again.

What's the best way of handling that? Putting the POST data in the session? But then, after successful login, I want to create the database entry in the original controller/action (so as to not duplicate code), and issuing a POST request from within my application (in the after-successful-login-method) seems strange. Any better ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're not mentioning how you do your authentication, so i suspect that you do it manually. If you use(and i would strongly recommend you do), a gem like Devise for registration, you just need to add Devise's authentication helper to your controllers, to do that.

To do it manually, every time the user registers, you set a session id variable that is tied to him/her. Then, you just check that to see whether he/she is registered. If not, you just do not allow the action and redirect.

Comment: I do use devise, but the before_filter authenticate_user! will not help with POST requests, will it? 
Again, I want to redirect user to the login page and - after successful authorization - back to the create method that handles the POST request

Comment: yes, it will work for post as well, for every action of the controller :) If you want to redirect back, just use redirect_to :back.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that - any idea on how to make authenticate_user! integrate with omniauth. My sign-in process is through Facebook with omniauth. So I would want authenticate_user! to redirect to Facebook, and then back to my POST request...

Comment: i haven't done that, but this should explain how to do it : https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

Comment: Thx. Just to make sure: authenticate_user! will redirect me to login page. Then you propose using redirect_to :back, but how is that supposed to work for POST requests? redirect_to will issue a 302...

Comment: I suppose that you would want to redirect back upon successful request,right ? If the user is not logged in, you would want to show the log in screen, there is no point in redirecting back. So, there should not be a problem there.

Comment: Well, I don't really want to redirect, but rather resume the POST request. 
Imagine the scenario: you are not signed in and fill out a long form, let's say for a comment. You then hit the submit button which will trigger a POST request. Since you are not signed in, you cannot create the comment but you are first redirected to the login page. You enter your credentials. Now after authorization, the comment should be created, i.e. you shouldn't have to fill out the long form again, and you shouldn't have to click the submit button again.
Maybe this makes it clearer?